# How to access hidden_attribute functions from the R source?

Tags: c, r

I want to use the following function in R.

```
double attribute_hidden chebyshev_eval(double x, const double *a, const int n)
{
    double b0, b1, b2, twox;
    int i;

    if (n < 1 || n > 1000) ML_ERR_return_NAN;

    if (x < -1.1 || x > 1.1) ML_ERR_return_NAN;

    twox = x * 2;
    b2 = b1 = 0;
    b0 = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
b2 = b1;
b1 = b0;
b0 = twox * b1 - b2 + a[n - i];
    }
    return (b0 - b2) * 0.5;
}
```

For reference, this is part of the R source code for chebyshev polynomials.

I can't seem to find a way to reach `hidden_attribute` functions in R. I tried doing the calculation manually for a real use case, but I'm running into errors:

```
gamcs=c(    +.8571195590989331421920062399942e-2,
+.4415381324841006757191315771652e-2,
+.5685043681599363378632664588789e-1,
-.4219835396418560501012500186624e-2,
+.1326808181212460220584006796352e-2,
-.1893024529798880432523947023886e-3,
+.3606925327441245256578082217225e-4,
-.6056761904460864218485548290365e-5,
+.1055829546302283344731823509093e-5,
-.1811967365542384048291855891166e-6,
+.3117724964715322277790254593169e-7,
-.5354219639019687140874081024347e-8,
+.9193275519859588946887786825940e-9,
-.1577941280288339761767423273953e-9,
+.2707980622934954543266540433089e-10,
-.4646818653825730144081661058933e-11,
+.7973350192007419656460767175359e-12,
-.1368078209830916025799499172309e-12,
+.2347319486563800657233471771688e-13,
-.4027432614949066932766570534699e-14,
+.6910051747372100912138336975257e-15,
-.1185584500221992907052387126192e-15,
+.2034148542496373955201026051932e-16,
-.3490054341717405849274012949108e-17,
+.5987993856485305567135051066026e-18,
-.1027378057872228074490069778431e-18,
+.1762702816060529824942759660748e-19,
-.3024320653735306260958772112042e-20,
+.5188914660218397839717833550506e-21,
-.8902770842456576692449251601066e-22,
+.1527474068493342602274596891306e-22,
-.2620731256187362900257328332799e-23,
+.4496464047830538670331046570666e-24,
-.7714712731336877911703901525333e-25,
+.1323635453126044036486572714666e-25,
-.2270999412942928816702313813333e-26,
+.3896418998003991449320816639999e-27,
-.6685198115125953327792127999999e-28,
+.1146998663140024384347613866666e-28,
-.1967938586345134677295103999999e-29,
+.3376448816585338090334890666666e-30,
-.5793070335782135784625493333333e-31)
ngam = 22
y = .8
x = y*2-1
b1 = b2 = 0
b0 = 0
twox = x * 2

n = ngam
a = gamcs

for (i in 1:n) {
b2 = b1
b1 = b0
b0 = twox * b1 - b2 + a[n - i]
}

(b0 - b2) * 0.5
```

(As taken from https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0b493ddbefbc3cc06f675841c4672b3197dbfbbb/src/nmath/gamma.c#L143 and https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0b493ddbefbc3cc06f675841c4672b3197dbfbbb/src/nmath/chebyshev.c#L69. The value for `y` is a dummy value with property `abs(y * 2 - 1)<=1.1`)

Calculating manually is not only tedious, it also results in a zero-value for `b0`, so the end result `(b0 - b2) * 0.5` doesn't return a value.

A workaround would be to access the function directly. This is a problem because `attribute_hidden` functions can't be accessed from R.

I'd like to know if there's a function, workaround, command etc. that will show these calculations. E.g. `ShowCalculations(chebyshev_eval(.6,gamcs,ngam))`.

Preferrably the function also shows / replicates the calculation for each line, or each iteration of the `for`-loop, and the likes.

Note: I'm aware but not terribly savvy of the `Rprintf` option. My knowledge of `C` code is limited so if one decides to propose that option, some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All you're asking is how to write the `c` code snippet in `R`?  First of all, that's not appropriate for SO; second why not use the chebyshev functions available in your referenced `R` package (or many other packages)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks us to write code for him.

Comment: Nowhere did I explicitly ask to write code for me. I'm asking if there's a function, package, workaround or whatever that allows me to access these functions. E.g. `ShowCalculations(chebyshev_eval(.8,gamcs,ngam))` or something.

Comment: You're asking for access to a chunk of `c` code which is already accessible via the identified package.  Do you understand how `R` accesses functions?